# Use a value object which contains generic ILists with a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization

I have a value object which contains multiple generic lists:

```
public IList<SomeClass> MyList { get; set; }
// ...
```

Now I cant serialize that to make it work with a web service. How could I do that?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I think you can use the NetDataContractSerializer if you want to move beyond the standards. But this requires .NET -> .NET communication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx

Comment: How would that look like using List<T>?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the existing object, then your main option is to use a DTO that looks *similar* to the existing object, but which has properties / behaviours that the serializer you are using (XmlSerializer for asmx, DataContractSerializer by default for svc) can handle. For example, it would have:

```
public List<SomeClass> MyList {get;set;}
```

or even:

```
public List<SomeClassDto> MyList {get;set;}
```

You might be able to map between these representations using AutoMapper, or do it by hand.

If you are using WCF, you might also be able to swap the serializer at runtime to support generic interface-based lists like `IList<T>`

Comment: What if I can change the existing object? How would I do that?

Comment: Yeah, but how would the syntax be for my example...I cant make it run. Thanks

Comment: public List<SomeClass> MyList { get; set; } - what happens if you use that?